# Docker tutorial 'Getting Started' doesn't work

Tags: docker

I have Ubuntu 20.04, Mozilla Firefox 87.0, Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90.

I am trying to run the Docker [Getting-started tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/). I read a couple of posts from stack overflow to not avail. Also I checked this [ToDo App (localhost:3000) shows no UI in Browser #9](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/9) and this [enter link description here](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/121) again to not avail. I do,

`sudo docker build -t getting-started .`
`sudo docker run -dp 3000:3000 getting-started`

and then when I go to  `http://localhost:3000` I get,

In Firefox,
[image]

in Chrome the following images alternate,
[image]
[image]

When I run, `sudo docker ps -a` I get,
[image]

Finally, do you suggest any Docker tutorial for beginners? I want to have enough understanding for Docker so that I can write scripts to manage docker images.

Comment: try `-p3000:80` instead of `-p3000:3000`

Comment: I tried it but instead of showing the app, it shows the local tutorial page.

Comment: Are all of the geting-started containers on the same port?

Answer (score 7):

You might be building and running the Dockerfile outside the "app" directory which has this behaviour. As the tutorial says, first go to the app directory, create a Dockerfile there and then build and run. This should work.

3000:80 opens the tutorial because the default Dockerfile builds the docker/getting-started which is the tutorial.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had to put 4000:3000 in the first lesson. I could see that when I omitted -d in the call. It then told me it was listening to port 3000.

Answer (score 3):

Might be the problem something is blocking the port on your machine so try to Replace the port to 80 instead of 3000.
Change from

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 getting-started
```

to

```
docker run -dp 3000:80 getting-started
```

and then open browser and hit `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 is correct but I would like to give a little explanation as to why you have to change "3000:3000" to "3000:80".

The port number before the colon represents the outgoing port and the port number after the colon represents the internal port inside the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

"As the tutorial says, first go to the app directory, create a Dockerfile there and then build and run."

This solves the problem. If you build and run from the root - there is existing Dockerfile in there, it want work. Go to app folder, create Dockerfile with the content from the tutorial, build and run.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the tutorial asks you to delete the container, then restart the updated version. But it forgets to mention that you need to rebuild the updated version of the image.
So what you need to do is rebuild the updated version of imagine:

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

I hope this helps